# Inserting in mongoose table that is not associated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'll be grateful for help with Mongoose. I have table users, orders and companies. When I create order or company tables i associate them with user table via virtual foreign key.

My problem is that i want to submit/create order via form with data origin,destination and when i input **company** (if i maybe insert company id or name) it gets associated with company table and gets also inserted in company table under orders {}

How should I make this model or route?

Thank you very much for help.

order model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    origin: {
        type: String
    },
    destination: {
        type: String
    },
????company:{
        // type: String
        // type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Company'
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);

module.exports = Order;
```

company model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Order = require("./order");

const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    oib: {
        type: Number
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    address:{
        type: String
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    drivers: [
        {
            driver: {
                type: Number
            }
    }
    ],
    orders: [
        {
            order: {
                type: Number
            }
    }
]
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

//Orders Foreign key
companySchema.virtual("order", {
    ref: "Order",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "company",
  });

const Company = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);

module.exports = Company;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand well. A few years ago I had a similar problem.
I solved my problem with Save/Validate Hooks
Doc: Save/Validate Hooks in https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#order

Basically, in the pre-validate function, I have checked if the object in your case `order` has either `objectId` as filed `company` value or another object or string with company `name`.

In the case of `objectId`, I have changed nothing.
In the case of the name (in my case I had a subobject of (name, address, etc...) I started the necessary logic to find or insert missed data, and replace the field `company` with a newly created or fetched ID.

So the later validation and save could be successful.